# Playing consecutive audio sounds in ReactJS. Delay issue when live

Tags: reactjs, audio

I'm trying to play a set of audio files one after the other ( example Chime - Beep, Beep, Beep ), and this works quite well on localhost with no issues.

When I upload it to the server it has Promise Rejected issues, it seems to be that some of the sounds take too long to download and therefore don't get played before the timer moves on to the next sound.

```
playSoundPattern = (sounds, times, durations, index) => {
       console.log("index = "+ index);
       var sound = sounds[0];
       var duration = durations[0];
       if (index > times[0]) {
           sound = sounds[1];
           duration = durations[1];
       }
       console.log(sound);
       console.log(this.player);
       this.player.src = sound;
       this.player.play();
       var total = times[0] + times[1];
       if (index < total) {
           console.log("playing " + times);
           setTimeout(this.playSoundPattern, duration, sounds, times, durations, index + 1);
       }
   }
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to many songs you can prepare all of them before and play when all are ready.

```
let songs = [];
[ "song_1", "song_2" ].forEach(function(filename) {
    songs[filename] = new Audio();
    songs[filename].src = "/path/to/songs/" + filename + ".";
    songs[filename].addEventListener("load", function() {
        songs[filename] = this;
    });
 });
```

Now inside songs there are only loaded songs.

Comment: Sounds promising (no pun).  Will give it a go and report.